# Relationships between models in Rails Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've been playing around with STI in rails and had a question about associating records with a specific model.

Say I have a Product model with the following schema:

```
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  url_name   :string(255)      not null
#  cover_img  :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
```

From this Product model, I create 2 inherited models:

Foo:

```
class Foo < Product

end
```

Bar:

```
class Bar < Product

end
```

Say I save a record to Foo(A), and a record to Bar(B). When I call Product.all, I expect to get all records A and B. However when i call Foo.all or Bar.all I expect to only retrieve A and B respectively, but what happening is that when I call either Foo.all or Bar.all, I get the result I get when call Product.all. How to I configure this relationship to get the expected results?

I am using rails 3.2.6 and Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a 'type' column to your products table so that ActiveRecord can distinguish between instances of the different types. This column should have a string type, like:

```
create_table :products do |t|
  # your other columns
  t.string :type
end
```

Comment: Yup, and just to elaborate a little further, Rails will then automatically use this type column for queries and casting to the appropriate class when instantiated.

Comment: That's correct, although this is a poorly documented feature, IMHO. That being said, this feature can lead to a rather weak design, so I would consider it thoroughly before proceeding. I would usually try to solve a problem like this with composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: There was some effort put into a [guide on STI](https://github.com/lifo/docrails/pull/100) a few months ago, but it seems like it didn't really go anywhere. While not perfect for every problem, STI can be really useful when applied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in how you are saving the object. You're probably saving them as either a Foo or a Bar, and *not* as a Product as you should be. When I use inherited models like you are, I'm generally only doing so to inherit communal ways to identify their datas.

So I would have for example, a Question, and two different types of questions like a Grammar and a Visual that would both inherit Question. But I would be saving the Object as question in the QuestionsController.

Just like you should be saving your objects with the ProductsController.